# phpunit getContent return empty

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit

I am learning Laravel 5.4, Still new to Laravel and PHPUnit. Everything is working great after following online basic tutorial.

This test function is working correctly when run phpunit

```
public function testBasicExample()
{
    $response = $this->call( 'GET' , '/welcome');

    $this->assertTrue(strpos($response->getContent(), 'Laravel') !== false);

}
```

Problem comes when I try to test Api

Steps I took

1. Create Api route for books
2. Return all users from users talbe as json from localhost/api/books/

> ```
> public function index()
> {
>   $users = DB::table('users')->get()->toJson();
>   echo $users;
> }
> ```

3. I open the link in browser and json is returned correctly
4. copy and pasted json into online json validator jsonlint and it is valid.
5. Create a new test function

> ```
> public function test_index_method_returns_all_books()
> {
>     $response = $this->call( 'GET' , '/api/books/');
>       $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode()); 
>
>     $data = json_decode($response->getContent(),true);
>     $this->assertJson($data);
> }
> ```

6. run phpunit 
   200 status test passed but assertJson did not pass.
7. I tried to do var_dump for $response->getContent() and found out it return empty.

now I am not able to get getContent() for api/book/. Does anyone know if there is a solution for this?

Thanks.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcxfD.png)

Comment: I am having similar issue where the curl call returns proper JSON response in the content, but an API call shows the class object information in public $original but the public $content is '{}'. Did you find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try create some data with a factory before you call the api:

e.g.:

```
factory(\App\Books::class, 20)->create();
```

then

```
$response = $this->call( 'GET' , '/api/books/');
```

If you had set ":memory:" as your database on phpunit.xml, you will no longer see any data from your local database, that's why you should use factory instead.